# how to open file in firebreath?

Tags: php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi, firebreath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple hello world NPAPI plugin for Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652034/a-simple-hello-world-npapi-plugin-for-google-chrome)
>   [How to open a file which includes in Chrome extension by C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339059/how-to-open-a-file-which-includes-in-chrome-extension-by-c-c)

originally i wanted to develop a chrome extension to open a file on the user's pc.

I wanted to use php `fopen` some SO users said that I have to use NPAPI instead and said that this is a duplicate question and deleted my question.

I just want to know why can't I use `fopen`? And if i really don't have other options, then how to open a file using firebreath?

When i go to this [section of the docs](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Linux#BuildingonLinux-BuildthePlugin) i don't see the snippets.

i know that moderators gonna come to my question saying that this is a dupe and [link to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339059/how-to-open-a-file-which-includes-in-chrome-extension-by-c-c) I'm one step ahead lol

I don't understand a thing from the accepted answer and i don't understand what file he edited.

the second answer give [this link](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Tips+and+Tricks#TipsandTricks-GettingtheURLofthecurrentpage) but i can't see the snippets! can you?

I'm on linux mint 12, 32 bit

**let me change the question. Can i do this in java? Flashgot  got some jar files in the source code :)**

install flashgot using chrome, a file called **flashgot-1.3.9-tb+sm+fx.xpi** will be downloaded, change that to **flashgot-1.3.9-tb+sm+fx.zip** unzip it and go to the **chrome folder**

Can i do it in python? every linux distro has python by default

Comment: i prefer to do it in php if i can or ajax... the point is, i don't want to use npapi unless i really have to

Comment: If you want to get questions answered, it usually helps to avoid swearing... The style of the linked page is apparently broken in Chrome, but fine in FF.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche if you believe that the question should be edited, feel free to modify it as you wish sir

Comment: If you don't understand an answer to a question, post a comment on the answer asking for more details, don't post a duplicate question with a rant.

Comment: @smorgan if i post a comment then the user may not answer, I'd rather ask my own question and have more users looking at it, I'll have bigger chance to get an answer

Comment: @smorgan the dupe ypu posted has 2 answers the first answer has link to how to create a ff extension and the 2nd answer has a link that does not work...i want to build a google chrome extension so why would i learn how to create a ff extension?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche hahahaah the guy ever!! you made my day :D anyway I want to change the question a bit otherwise I'll be getting dupes all day long lol!! **CAN I DO THIS IN JAVA???** [Flashgot](http://flashgot.net/) has some jar files in the source code!

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know why can't I use fopen?

Because JavaScript isn't C.

More generally, there's no way for arbitrary web pages to run arbitrary native code on your computer because otherwise clicking a link could take you to a page that would steal every file on your computer and then erase your hard drive.

Comment: well can i use java? flashgot has some jar files in the source code

Comment: see my edit, if you want to know where is java in flashgot

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebreath then you're in C++, so you can use fopen if you wish.  Keep in mind that you would have the same privileges as the browser, which running as a user probably can't write places like Program Files, etc.

You can't use fopen in javascript. I don't know why a "building firebreath on linux" page would ever have snippets on how to open a file; since firebreath is just C++ I don't know why we'd need to add docs for opening a file at all.. it's just C++. Open a file like you would in any other C++ application.

The other question has all the information you need to figure out where your file is; they didn't include specifics on how to do the operation itself because you don't need those specifics; you can get them anywhere.  Try googling "open a file in c++" and you'll get lots of hits.

Comment: i know how to open a file in c++ i just don't like c++ - i know french i just don't like to speak french - see? anyway what you are suggesting is to create a c++ file that opens the file and compile the project? that easy? that simple? there are hundreds of files in firebreath and hundred of docs...

Comment: i'm starting to understand what flashgot did, but not 100% sure! they created a jar file, which would open the downloader, created a simple api that they will call when you click on a link.... I'm gonna try and do the same thing, firefox does not care what your extension has as long as it does not have to deal with it, i believe i can do the same with chrome, one python file to do the stuff, and a simple api, use xml to do the stuff.... 2 or 3 files, instead of hundreds...let me try :)

Comment: your question reads "How to open a fire in FireBreath"  I have answered that question.  If you want to ask a different question, please create a different question. On an unrelated note, java can be used but will pop up a dialog verifying that the user wants to allow access to the drive.  However, that's a completely *completely* different question from the one you ask. For new questions, create a new question.

Comment: no i respect everything you and your team have done to create firebreath, i really do but did you read [this docs](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Creating+a+New+Plugin+Project#CreatingaNewPluginProject-Whatjusthappened) `Arguably the most important file in the project to get right, this is where 90% of the configuration happens. Nearly all of the things you were prompted for by fbgen.py go directly into this file. Don't worry – you can change it if you want to. Configuration options from this file are used to generate other files that are critical to your plugin configuration`

Comment: and you say i need to create a separate c++, so 'm just confused! so confused! like a lot lol :D so i don't work there? i just create a c++ file and compile? and what about the js in my extension? how to communicate between the files?

Comment: You ask about using FireBreath; FireBreath is C++. If you don't want to use FireBreath (and thus dont' want to use C++), don't ask about C++.  You could possibly do it another way, such as with java, but you ask about using FireBreath, so I answered with how FireBreath would do it.

Regarding your quote of the docs, talking about PluginConfig.cmake; that is metadata. It has no bearing on this discussion that I can find. It has nothing to do with creating a file.